# C++ - Extracting core submatrix, inverting it and reusing it in the big inverse

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-inverse

I have a `matrix` of fixed  `size = 900*900`.
I fill its elements by doing

```
for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
      {
    for (int j=i; j<size; ++j)
    {
      matrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i]= something(i,j);
```

where `something(i,j)` is a function that I defined previously.
This is such that the final `matrix` looks like this

```
    0000000000
    0000000000
    00------00 
    00------00
    00------00 
    00------00
    0000000000
    0000000000
```

wher the dashed linen denotes values differnt from 0.
The picture I gave is of course only to give an explanation: the size is 900 X 900 and my problem is that I need to invert this matrix. SVD performs badly unfortunately. As you can see this matrix is symmetric and has this peculiar "block"structure. My idea is to isolate the "core" of the matrix (the values different from 0, which shoudl give me a much smaller submatrix, invert this submatrix and re-substitute in the bigger inverse,

```
0000000000
0000000000
00iiiiii00 
00iiiiii00
00iiiiii00 
00iiiiii00
0000000000
0000000000
```

where the `i` are the elemets of the inverse of teh smaller submatrix.
How can I efficiently declare and fill this submatrix starting from the code I posted, which fills the big matrix, in `c++`?

Comment: You say you want the inverse matrix, but this matrix is clearly not invertible due to the rows and columns of zeroes

Comment: Why don't you use a library, like Eigen? It will certainly be better that writing a home-brewed solution. And yes, this particular matrix is not even invertible

Comment: You are right this is not invertible, this is why I was previously using a SVD. I guess technically speaking what I am looking for is a pseudo-inverse

Comment: Do you want a matrix such that you can multiply it with the original matrix and get a matrix whose "center block" is the identity matrix? In that case, yes you can pull out the center matrix and invert that

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this efficiently, as in without copying the inner matrix, you need support for strided matrices. E.g. Eigen provides this via their [`Eigen::Map`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) abstraction. The inner matrix has the obvious origin and extents but the stride is the same as the containing matrix.

EDIT: This is tagged C++, but it isn't clear if you are using some sort of linear algebra library. If implementing your own manipulation, you can do strides yourself via pointer arithmetic or creative indexing. If passing the data to a library, it will have to have a mechanism for strides or it will not work. Numpy does support interfacing to strided external data.